# PrimeNg DataList not showing in Easy App

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm copying the example from PrimeNg website for a datalist, but can't get it to show the data. It just says "No records found". The json file is in the right place, although I don't know if it's pulling data from it or not. Seems to me that "value" in the html file doesn't know where to get the data from.

Here is a component file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}

export class DataListDemo implements OnInit {

      cars: Car[];

      constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.carService.getCarsLarge().then(cars => this.cars = cars);
      }
  }
```

Here's my service file:

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getCarsLarge() {
        return this.http.get('/assets/cars-large.json')
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => <Car[]> res.json().data)
                    .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
```

Here's my module file:

```
import { CarService } from './car.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {DataListModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpModule, DataListModule
  ],
  providers: [CarService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's my html file:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<p-dataList [value]="cars">
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
      Car content
  </ng-template>
</p-dataList>
```

Here's my type file:

```
export interface Car {
    vin;
    year;
    brand;
    color;
}
```

Comment: I have imported primemg modules like this way. see if it helps `import {DataTableModule} from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/components/button/button';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p-dataList [value]="cars">
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
      Car content
  </ng-template>
</p-dataList>`

In this section you posted. Inside ng-template you are not really trying to do any interpolation of the Cars data. If this is the actual code you have now, you have to change it to something like below.

```
<ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9 car-details">
            <div class="ui-g">
                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Vin: </div>
                <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{car.vin}}</div>

                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Year: </div>
                <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{car.year}}</div>

                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Brand: </div>
                <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{car.brand}}</div>

                <div class="ui-g-2 ui-sm-6">Color: </div>
                <div class="ui-g-10 ui-sm-6">{{car.color}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also i would suggest you to check if the Json data is really loaded. You can check in developer tools networks tab.